# Change image with animation direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have two images of a cow. I want to show it walking from left to right and from right to left.
currently I am using one image for both state , I want to use two images where the cow faces left when walking left and facing right when walking right.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `src` attribute with the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) when the animation direction changes and therefore change the image :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/58STp/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      function cowLeft() {
          $("img#b").attr('src','PATH_TO_IMG_COW_FACING_LEFT').animate({left: "-=100"}, 3500, "swing", cowRight);
      }
      function cowRight() {
          $("img#b").attr('src','PATH_TO_IMG_COW_FACING_RIGHT').animate({left: "+=100"}, 3500, "swing", cowLeft);
      }
      cowRight();
  });
```

Comment: Kindly please check my question bottom section where i have put another section which im getting stuck. please advice me

Comment: @user3786234 this is a different quetion, you should delete it here and ask a new question for it.

Comment: since im new user i have to wait another 90minutes for next question posting , thats why i place it here. please help

Comment: @user3786234 I am not used to canvas, so I can't help efficiently. The only advice I can give you is wait and post a new question with apropriate tags.